# Evans, chapter 6 exercise 2

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

Consider the following question

[image]

I know I'm supposed to show boundedness and coercivity but haven't made much progress.
Do I need to integrate by parts? Also I'm really interested in seeing the coercivity step

The norm I am considering is the $H^1_{0}$ norm

Comment: What are the assumptions on $a_{ij}$?

Comment: They’re symmetric?

Comment: Questions should not be posted as picture but as text to allow for future search. Also the title is not helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prove that is bounded is straightforward as soon as the coefficients are bounded. For the coercivity, I guess you are assuming that the matrix $a$ of the coefficients is uniformly elliptic. Then you just have to use Poincaré inequality.

I just focus on coercivity. Call $A$ the uniformly elliptic matrix whose entries are the $a_{ij}$. The fact that $A$ is uniformly elliptic means that there exits $\lambda >0$ such that $A v\cdot v\geq \lambda |v|^2$ for every $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$. You have
$$
\int_\Omega A \nabla u\cdot \nabla u +c u^2 \geq \int_\Omega \lambda |\nabla u|^2 +c u^2 \geq \int_\Omega \frac{\lambda}{2} |\nabla u|^2 + \frac{\lambda}{2}|\nabla u|^2 +c u^2\;.
$$
Therefore, by the Poincaré inequality, i.e.,
$$
\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 \geq \frac{1}{c_P^2}\int_\Omega |u|^2 \, ,$$
applied to one of the $\lambda/2$ terms, you have
$$
\int_\Omega \frac{\lambda}{2} |\nabla u|^2 + \frac{\lambda}{2}|\nabla u|^2 +c u^2
\geq
\int_\Omega \frac{\lambda}{2} |\nabla u|^2 + (c+\frac{\lambda}{2 c_P^2})|u|^2\; .$$
Therefore it is sufficient to take the $\alpha$ you were looking for as
$$
\alpha:=\frac{\lambda}{2 c_P^2}
$$
because the $|u|^2$ term is nonegative as soon as $c+\frac{\lambda}{2 c_P^2}\geq 0$, i.e., as soon as $c\geq =-\frac{\lambda}{2 c_P^2}=:- \alpha$.

Comment: Ok that helps but I'd like to see more detail if possible

Comment: I added details.

Comment: How do we have coercivity here. We want to show that $B(u,u) \ge K||u||^2$ Ok I see that we want u to be positive but then what would be the constant on the outside

Comment: It is straightforward. But it depends on the norm you are considering on $H_0^1$. Please before asking more, specify in your original question the norm you are considering on $H_0^1$; if possible, substitute the image with a real text; accept the answer.

Comment: Why did you break the norm of the gradient into 2 pieces. If the Bilinear form had 3 pieces would we break it down into 3 pieces? Is there an interpretation for uniform ellipticity (its meaning in words)?

Comment: ...............

Comment: Uniform ellipticity means that at every point $x$ where the symmetric matrix $A(x)$ is defined, the eigenvalues of $A(x)$ are greater than or equal to $\lambda$.

Comment: do you have email address?

Comment: @Rem I am using that the matrix is uniformly elliptic. If I understood the question.

Comment: I think you are missing the definition of uniform ellipticity (that I recall in the post). But Google it and I think it will be clear what I did. (It is part of the uniform ellipticity hypothesis that you can boud with that lambda if you "evaluate" the matrix A at equal vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Since Kosh has proved the coercitivity condition, I will prove the boundedness one.

The bilinear form associated to $\mathcal L$ is
$$B(u,v)=-\int_\Omega\sum_{i,j}^n(a_{ij}u_{x_i})_{x_j}v+\int_\Omega\sum_{i,j=1}^ncuv=\int_\Omega\sum_{i,j=1}^na_{ij}u_{x_i}v_{x_j}+\int_\Omega cuv$$
where in the second equality we used the integration by parts formula, toghether with the fact that $v$ vanishes in $\partial\Omega$ (recall that functions in $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ are precisely those whose trace is equal to zero in the boundary $\partial\Omega$).

Now
\begin{align}
   |B(u,v)|&\leq\int_\Omega\sum_{i,j=1}^n|a_{ij}||u_{x_i}||v_{x_j}|+\int_\Omega |c||u||v|\\
&\leq C_1\left(\int_\Omega|u_{x_i}|v_{x_j}|+\int_\Omega |u||v|\right)\\
&\leq C_1\left(\int_\Omega|\nabla u||\nabla v|+\int_\Omega|u||v|\right)\\
&\leq C_1(\lVert\nabla u\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}\lVert\nabla v\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}+\lVert u\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}\lVert v\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)})\\
&\leq C_2\lVert\nabla u\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}\lVert\nabla v\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq C_2\lVert\nabla u\rVert_{H_0^1(\Omega)}\lVert\nabla v\rVert_{H_0^1(\Omega)}
\end{align}

where in the first inequality we used the usual inequality involving the norm of an integral, and the integral of a norm, toghether with the triangular inequality, in the second we used the coefficients $a_{ij}$ and $c$ are bounded in $\Omega$ (we are supposing that they belong to $L^\infty(\Omega)$), in the third we simply use that
$$\sqrt{|\nabla u|}=\sqrt{u_{x_1}^2+\dots+u_{x_n}^2}\geq|u_{x_i}|$$
for all $i=1,\dots,n$, In the forth we are using Hölder's inequality, and in the fifth we are using Poincaré's inequality. Finally, the last inequality follows from the definition of the norm in the Sobolev spaces $W^{k,p}$.